# Entity Frame Work Core 6.0.1 is still trying to using a column I deleted from an Entity, when I add rows and Save

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Entity Frame Work Core 6.0.1 is still trying to using a column I deleted from an Entity, when I add rows and Save. I get the error:

> "message": "Invalid column name ''.\r\nInvalid column name
> 'PlanTypeId'.",
> "type": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
> "raw": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PlanTypeId'.\r\nInvalid column name
> 'PlanTypeId'.\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__188_0(Task`1 result)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()\r\n
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__271_0(Object obj)\r\n
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n--- End
> of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
> currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)\r\n--- End of stack trace
> from previous location ---\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection
> connection, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\nClientConnectionId:61d308a0-2c57-470c-9181-9bf939c8073f\r\nError
> Number:207,State:1,Class:16"

The entity no longer has that column PlanTypeId from the error above. ILookup is just an interface so it does not matter. The entity in question follows:

```
public class AgreementType : ILookup
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Fund> Funds { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

The migration up code that Microsoft generated did not delete the Foreign Key column when I added the migration, so I updated the Up() code like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropIndex("IX_AgreementTypes_PlanTypeId", "AgreementTypes");
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey("FK_AgreementTypes_PlanTypes_PlanTypeId", "AgreementTypes");
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn("PlanTypeId", "AgreementTypes");
        }
```

When I run the Up Migration the database updates properly and the column is removed from the database. But when I try and run code to add records to the database and save I get the above error.

```
public async Task<bool> SeedAgreementTypesAsync(List<AgreementType> data)
{
    if (!_context.AgreementTypes.Any())
    {
        await _context.AgreementTypes.AddRangeAsync(data);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems that Entity Framework is getting this column from somewhere, but I can't see where.

Answer (score 0):

There was some code in ContextModelsnapshot that still had the PlanTypeId. I believe this is because I modified the Up migration call manually so since the column was not deleted by the migration in the snapshot file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).